# Getting text inputs to work in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a few text inputs on my form that are not working correctly. I cannot see what is being typed and the fields unfocus after just one character.
Here's the pieces of my code where it's at:

```
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          key: uuid(),
          title: "",
          author: "",
          questions: [],
          answers: []
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.addQuestion = this.addQuestion.bind(this);
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this)
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        // componentDidMount() is a React lifecycle method
        this.addQuestion();
      }

      handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        });
      }

//yada yada

render() {
//yada yada
    {this.state.questions.map((question, index) => {
                    return (
                      <li>
                      <div key={uuid()}>
                        Question
                        {question}<br />
                        <button onClick={ () => this.removeItem(index) }>
                      Remove Question
                    </button>
                        Answer Choices<br />
                        {Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => (
                          <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" key={uuid()}/>
                            <input type="text" key={uuid()} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                          </div>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
//yada yada
}
export default App;
```

I am very new to this so any tips directly related to this issue or not would be super helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving your elements unique keys each render with `uuid()`, which will destroy the element and mount a new one. Remove the `key={uuid()}` and it will work.

```
{this.state.questions.map((question, index) => {
  return (
    <li key={index}>
      <div>
        Question
        {question}
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(index)}>
          Remove Question
        </button>
        Answer Choices<br />
        {Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_element, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </li>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried it out but it didn't seem to work

Comment: @dorkycam I updated the answer. Why are you even using `uuid()` as key? Please read the [section on List and Keys in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: This worked, thanks. I was using `uuid()` as a key because I have four answer inputs per question, and the number of questions varies upon the user. The user has the ability to add as many questions as they would like (i'll probably add a limit to that later) so I thought that in order to keep track of which set of questions goes with which question I gave them all `uuid()`. I didn't come up with this myself, it was a tip from someone else. I also found other articles online saying that using `index` as a key is a bad idea.

Comment: @dorkycam I can't say for certain, but I think you misunderstood that tip. If you give a `uuid` to each object in your data, that would make sense. That way you could reuse that same `uuid` every render, but setting `key` as a new `uuid()` each render is a very bad idea.

Comment: Lol ok, how do you suggest I give each object a `uuid()` then?

Comment: @dorkycam You could give each `question` and `answer` a `id: uuid()` in the response to your network request and use that in render, *not* run `uuid()` each render. Don't you see the issue?

Comment: Ahhh, ok. And yes, I've noticed that there is an issue there. Thanks again for all the help!